# Reading multiply embedded variables from generic classes in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, tuples

Essentially I have the task of writing two methods: a zip method that turns a generic tuple containing two lists of generic objections into a list of tuples made up of elements of the aforementioned lists, and an unzip method that does the same thing in the other direction. I.e.:

```
({1, "banana", true}{asgard, 5.21e, "stupidhomework"})
=> unzip
{(1, asgard)("banana",5.21e)(true,"stupidhomework")}
=> zip
({1, "banana", true}{asgard, 5.21e, "stupidhomework"})
```

Further complicating this: the list is a simply linked immutable generic list with the structure

```
List<T>
public final T       head;
public final List<T> tail;
```

...And the tuples are equally generic; both elements of the tuple can be literally anything:

```
public class Tuple<A, B> {
public final A a;
public final B b;
```

So here's my problem: I have no idea how to get at elements a second layer down. For example, normally, I'd just do this-

```
   public static<A, B extends List> List unzip(Tuple<A, B> ListenTuple){
        List TupelnListe = new List(new Tuple(ListenTuple.a.head, ListenTuple.b.head));
```

-To get at the elements I need, two layers down. Unfortuantely, because Tuple is generic, it doesn't know that ListenTuple.a has to be a List, and therefore has a head. The analogous problem arises in zip with getting at a and b from the tuple. Oh, and I'm not allowed to typecast for some stupid arbitrary reason, although I'm not sure how that would help me.

...Basically, can anyone give me a pointer on how to get this started? They basically threw us into generics in class this week, and nobody gets it. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldnt unzip take a list of tuples and not a tuple of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
public static<A, B> List zip(Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> ListenTuple){
```

So that A and B are the elements of the list and a, b are now lists.

I am more familiar with C++ so am not sure if the differences prevent this somehow.

Comment: I think that might have done it! No more error message, at least. I'll finish my implementation and see if htat solves it.

Comment: @JonahStephenSwersey great!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend these signatures:

```
public static <A, B> List<Tuple<A, B>> zip(Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> x);
public static <A, B> Tuple<List<A>, List<B>> unzip(List<Tuple<A, B>> x);
```

See if you can figure it out from there